# Encode into an `enumerate` environment (Version 2)

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

From the following code, a selection from a multiple-choice test is rendered.  The four problems should be enumerated as `1.)`, `9.)`, `16.)`, and `25.)`.  How do I do that with an `enumerate` environment?

I typeset each problem twice - once in an `enumerate` environment and once in a `tabbing` environment.  For the first two problems - the problems that I want labeled `1.)` and `9.)` - I prefer the appearances given by the `tabbing` environment.  How do I get these appearances using the `enumerate` environment?  Maybe I would want something bigger than `topsep=\baselineskip` to separate "Express the following decimals as fractions" from the following choices and to separate "The sum of the (interior) angles of which of the following figures is not a multiple of $360^{\circ}$" from the following choices.

For the last two problems - the problems that I want labeled `16.)` and `25.)` - I want to know why the commands `\newlength{\Adelyn}`, `\settoheight{\Adelyn}{$\sqrt{b}$}`, and `topsep=\baselineskip` seem to be ignored.  There seems to be a lot more space between the first-level and second-level `enumerate` environments.  How do I get `i.)` `ii.)`, and `iii.)` across the first row and `iv.)` and `v.)` across the second row?  Why is `$\dfrac{1}{2} \log(a^{2}b)$` so poorly displayed in the choices for the last problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
  leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
  label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}, itemsep=8pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review of High School Algebra}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in


\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip, topsep=\baselineskip]
\item Express the following decimals as fractions.
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5cm]
    \item 1
    \item 0.25
    \item 0.025
    \item 0.0025
    \item 0.125
    \item 0.0125
    \item 1.25
    \item 0.0625
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}


\noindent \textbf{1.) }Express the following decimals as fractions.
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \hspace{1.25in}  \= \hspace{1.25in}  \= \hspace{1.25in} \= \hspace{1.25in} \= \kill
\> \textbf{i.) }1       \> \textbf{ii.) }0.25    \> \textbf{iii.) }0.025 \> \textbf{iv.) }0.0025 \\
\> \textbf{v.) }0.125   \> \textbf{vi.) }0.0125     \> \textbf{vii.) }1.25  \> \textbf{viii.) }0.0625
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.25in

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip, topsep=\baselineskip]
\item The sum of the (interior) angles of which of the following figures is not a multiple of $360^{\circ}$?
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip]
    \item triangle
    \item trapezoid
    \item isosceles trapezoid
    \item hexagon
    \item octagon
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}


\noindent \textbf{9.) }The sum of the (interior) angles of which of the following figures is not a multiple of $360^{\circ}$?
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2em} \= \hspace{1.5in}  \= \hspace{1.5in}  \= \hspace{1.5in} \= \kill
\> \textbf{i.) }triangle    \> \textbf{ii.) }trapezoid  \> \textbf{iii.) }isosceles trapezoid \\
\> \textbf{iv.) }hexagon    \> \textbf{v.) }octagon
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.25in

\newlength{\Adelyn}
\settoheight{\Adelyn}{$\sqrt{b}$}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=\baselineskip]
\item Simplify the following expressions. (Except for the first expression, the following expressions are equal to integers.)
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    %Set height for text.
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1.2\Adelyn]
    \item $\sqrt{0.25}$
    \item $\sqrt{0}$
    \item $\sqrt{36}$
    \item $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-1}$
    \item $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-8}$
    \item $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{(18)(12)}$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[topsep=\baselineskip]
\item $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, and $a^{2}b = 1000$. Which of the following expressions is an integer?
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    %Use height for text from previous problem.
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\Adelyn]
    \item $\log(a)$
    \item $\log(b)$
    \item $\log(ab)$
    \item $\log\bigl(\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{a^{2}b}\bigr)$
    \item $\dfrac{1}{2} \log(a^{2}b)$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could use `\item[25.)]` to set the label of the enumerate item explicitly.

Comment: There seem to be several questions here. For horizontal enumeration, I think you might like the `tasks` package. It's part of `exsheets`, which might also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this (obtained with `tasks`) is what you want:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newlength\labelwd
\settowidth\labelwd{\bfseries viii.)}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].), label-format=\bfseries, label-offset=1em, label-align=right, label-width
=\labelwd, before-skip =\medskipamount}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{% (
leftmargin=*, itemsep=12pt, label={\textbf{\arabic*.)}}}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{% (
label={\textbf{\roman*.)}}, itemsep=8pt}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\Large{\textbf{Review of High School Algebra}}\end{center}\vskip0.3in

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip, topsep=\baselineskip]
  \item Express the following decimals as fractions.
        \begin{tasks}(4)
          \task 1
          \task 0.25
          \task 0.025
          \task 0.0025
          \task 0.125
          \task 0.0125
          \task 1.25
          \task 0.0625
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
%

\begin{enumerate}[start =9]
  \item The sum of the (interior) angles of which of the following figures is not a multiple of $360^{\circ}$?
        \begin{tasks}(3)
          \task triangle
          \task trapezoid
          \task isosceles trapezoid
          \task hexagon
          \task octogon
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=\baselineskip]
  \item Simplify the following expressions. (Except for the first expression, the following expressions are equal to integers.)

        \begin{tasks}[before-skip =\bigskipamount](3)
          \task $\sqrt{0.25}$
          \task $\sqrt{0}$
          \task $\sqrt{36}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-1}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{-8}$
          \task $\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{(18)(12)}$
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[topsep=\baselineskip]
  \item $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, and $a^{2}b = 1000$. Which of the following expressions is an integer?
        \begin{tasks}[before-skip =\bigskipamount](3)
          \task $\log(a)$
          \task $\log(b)$
          \task $\log(ab)$
          \task $\log\bigl(\sqrt[\uproot{1} \leftroot{-1} 3]{a^{2}b}\bigr)$
          \task $\dfrac{1}{2} \log(a^{2}b)$
        \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `tasks` package looks nice!

Comment: @BernardI see that you have `\newlength\labelwd` and 
`\settowidth\labelwd{\bfseries viii.)}` in the preamble and that you have `\settasks{label-width=\labelwd}`.  What formatting is rendered by this?

Comment: `Tasks` uses a default width for labels, which is too small for roman numbering (except small numbers). So I introduced  a new length which ensures that, up to `xvi` , there is enough space for the label. As it is in the preamble, you may easily change it if necessary.

Comment: @Bernard  How does `\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].)}` render the list?  Please give me a link to the manual for this package.

Comment: `tsk[r]` means the counter displays in roman style. See § 4 of the documentation, which you may consult via `texdoc tasks` or [the TeX catalogue on line](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/tasks.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here. Normally this site works best if you ask one main question per post. However, I think you not be sure which parts can be disentangled. (The question about how some math is displayed should, however, be clearly separate.)

For the space in the first `enumerate` environment, you are getting the default `itemsep` space you asked for: viz, `itemsep=8pt` in

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{... itemsep=8pt}
```

The solution is to not set so big a default space if you dislike it, or overwrite it at the specific list with

```
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=<length>]
```

In your third list (viz, "the sum of the (interior)..."), you have set even larger values by writing

```
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\baselineskip, topsep=\baselineskip]
```

Change them if you want something different.

You are also starting a new enumerate environment for every question, which is ill-advised.  If you want to do what I think you are trying to do, you could nest them:

```
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Question 1

 \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Answer choice 1
   \item Answer choice 2
 \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\item Question 2
 \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item Answer choice 1
   \item Answer choice 2
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

To do it your way, you need to keep setting local things, which is inefficient.

Note that `topsep` in an enumerate environment sets the "top separation" between the previous paragraph/text and the first item, so putting it at your level-one list is not doing what you think it is. You mean to use it in the second-level list.

If you want the second-level lists to "grow" horizonatally, the `multicols` environment is not the correct approach. You would need to load `enumitem` with the `inline` option and then use the `enumerate*` environment:

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
...
\begin{enumerate*}
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate*}
```

The problem with `$\dfrac...$` is that the "d" presumably stands for "display". Maybe you want `$\tfrac...$`.

Finally, you can start enumerate environments at any arbitrary number with

```
\begin{enumerate}[start=33]% starts at 33
```

If you interrupt and resume a list, you can also use the option `resume` or `resume*`. See the manual of `enumitem` for more information.

Comment: With  inline lists, lists longer than on line won't be vertically aligned.

Comment: @jon  Right now, I have no regard for writing inefficient code.  First, I want to get a certain format for a multiple-choice test or for solutions to certain problems on a multiple-choice test.  Second, by repetition, I will get familiar with coding `enumerate` environments.

Comment: @jon  So, I eliminated `itemsep=8pt` and `\itemsep=12pt` from the options in the preamble.  For the first problem, I still get a big space between "Express the following ..." and the choices.  I removed `topsep=\baselineskip` from the first-level `enumerate` environment and put it in the second-level.    (You are right.  I did not know the option instructed `LaTeX` to set the inter-line spacing between the second-level `enumerate` environment and the preceding text.)

Comment: @jon  I do not know how to get `i.)`, `ii.)`, `iii.)`, and `iv.)` across the first row in the choices for the first problem.  Please provide the code for that, and I will mimic it for the other choices.  Remember, I do not care about efficiency.

Comment: @Adelyn -- to get things "across the first" row, you need `enumerate*` instead of `enumerate` as I said. But as Bernard explained, this is not designed to do what you want. However, as for your first comment, you are wrong: doing it the way you are currently doing it is not helping you learn how `enumerate` environments work because you aren't actually using the package the way it was designed. It is designed to do lists. If you only want to write a single number followed by text, then `enumerate` is the wrong environment. I'd suggest `\hangpara` instead combined with your own counter.

Comment: @jon  OK.  I'll use the `*` version of the `enumerate` environment.  I do want to make a list - in this case a list of questions.  I sometimes will want to skip some numbers - in this case problems are numbered `1.)`, `9.)`, `16.)`, and `25.)`.

Comment: @jon  For the first problem, I need to remove the extra space between "Express the following ..." and the choices.  (Remember, I deleted `itemsep=8pt` and `\itemsep=12pt` from the options in the preamble.)

Comment: That's what the comment about `start` is about. And, as I have said, `topsep` is what determines the space between the start of a list and the text that precedes it. (Here it is slightly complicated because of the nested list environment, but that is the main value you should change.)

Comment: @jon  If you can provide the code that will give me "the proper spacing," which is inter-line spacing in `text` mode between  `i.)`, `ii.)`, `iii.)`, and `iv.)` across the first row in the choices for the first problem, I can mimic it.  I am not getting "the proper spacing."  And I tried `\begin{enumerate*}`  ...  `\end{enumerate*}`  to get the lower-case Roman numerals across the rows.  The code would not compile.

Comment: Did you load `enumitem` with the appropriate options? I have already explained several times how to get the proper spacing, but I don't know what you are doing. The way you claim you want to start and stop multiple enumerate environments is plain wrong in my opinion, and probably is making your life *far* more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: @jon  You can see that I have `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble.  I just editing the code to have `\begin{enumerate*}` ... `\end{enumerate*}` for the first problem.

Comment: @jon  I posted one more request about this - `Encode into an `enumerate` environment (Version 3)`.  As you suggested, I made the post focused.  If you look, I guarantee you will agree.

Comment: I wrote `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}`, and stated the option was needed....